# Numerical differentiation with respect to a ln of (x)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, numerical-value

i want to compute the numerical derivative of a function that depends of x , but the derivative is with respect to a ln of x.

[image]

Suppose that ns is a function that depends of k, ¿how is the formula or how i can compute this numerical vaule?

Thanks!

Comment: `D[ns[k], k]/D[Log[k], k]`

Comment: `Dt[ns[k]]/Dt[Log[k]]`

Comment: See also [`ResourceFunction["ChainD"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ChainD)